# SSH into a Docker Machine instance

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on centos when I try to ssh from my system  (centos) to docker machine . It shows error : ssh:connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 22 :connection refused .
Does anyone know how to ssh into docker machine .

Comment: Could you please clarify the question to address the question raised in [my comment on @snap's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48451075/ssh-into-a-docker#comment83896599_48451255)?

Comment: Could you add details of the the steps you are trying to complete via ssh to the question. Docker provides [`docker exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) and [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) and an image build system which will likely cover you use case.

Comment: Sir I made an automation script using Python to automate configuration file of some of the softwares . Now I want to test that script on different distro of Linux so I installed docker and in docker I have centos and Ubuntu .                    My base os is centos now I want to transfer that script using scp command and then execute them on the distros on docker.                  But when I ssh or use scp command from my base os to send those file to the images in docker it shows error : connection refused

Answer (score 5):

Do you reallly need to use ssh, or do you just want to work in a shell inside the container?

If you just want to get "into" the container you could execute the following command:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER /bin/bash
```

This will execute the bash in interactive mode on a running container. Bash is here only a suggestion for a installed shell you want to use. CONTAINER must be replaced with the name or the hash of your docker container.

If you want to start a new container which you want to use directly inside the shell, you can do it this way (f.e. use the latest ubuntu image):

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: I read the OP as referring to the VM in which [Docker Machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/) runs containers, as opposed to a container inside that guest. As such, I'm not sure that this is pertinent -- anyone following this answer's advice would get a shell in the container inside the VM, not the VM's root namespace.

Comment: Sir I want to use ssh so that I can transfer some scripts from my base o.s to docker .

Comment: @user9269501 In case you want to share files only, you can use the `-v` tag

Comment: Sir please can you give a detail how can I use      -v tag to share files from by base o.s to docker .                                                                Thank you